# The listener does NOT stop! || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code:

```
// Listen for button click
const filter = i => i.customId === 'verification:start' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector(filter, { time: 30000 });

collector.on('collect', async i => {
  try {
    // Check if user has already been verified
    if (i.member.roles.cache.has(newVerifiedRole)) {
      await i.reply('You have already been verified!');
      return;
    }

    // Send captcha to user's DMs
    const dmChannel = await i.user.createDM();
    const captcha = generateCaptcha();
    const dmMessage = await dmChannel.send(`Please enter the following captcha within 30 seconds: **${captcha}**`);
    const dmFilter = m => m.author.id === i.user.id;
    const dmCollector = dmChannel.createMessageCollector(dmFilter, { max: 1, maxProcessed: 1, time: 30000 });

    // Check captcha response
    dmCollector.on('collect', async m => {
      if (m.content === captcha) {
        await dmChannel.send('You have been verified!');
        await i.member.roles.add(newVerifiedRole);
        await i.member.roles.remove(newUnverifiedRole);
        dmCollector.off('collect');
      } else {
        await dmChannel.send('Incorrect captcha. Please try again.');
        dmCollector.off('collect');
      }
    });

    dmCollector.on('end', async collected => {
      try {
        if (collected.size === 0) {
          await dmChannel.send('Time is up. Please try again.');
        }
        await message.edit({ components: [row] });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error updating message: ${err}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

When I click the "Verify" button it sends me the ${captcha} code in my DM. The problem is when I send back the **correct** captcha code it sends me `You have been verified!` and right after `Incorrect captcha. Please try again.` *(**Note:** Sometimes the Bot sends `Incorrect captcha. Please try again.` multiple times!)*! This problem persists because this the listener keeps running! Trying to use `dmCollector.stop();` does not stop the listener! Any answer is accepted! Thanks!!

Comment: Although it looks like the handy jQuery util, [`off`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html#emitteroffeventname-listener) is an alias for `removeListener()`, so it doesn't support the single parameter `.off("eventType")` syntax. You'll either need to store the event handler and pass it to `dmCollector.off("collect", myEventHandler)` ... or you could just use `.once(..)` instead of `.on(..)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either!
Me:
*Correct captcha code*
My Bot:
You have been verified!
Incorrect captcha. Please try again.
Incorrect captcha. Please try again.

Comment: I've already mentioned the day before yesterday that you will need to update your collector: `dmChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter: dmFilter, max: 1, maxProcessed: 1, time: 30000 })`